# I'm doing a project on Truchet tiling and I'm having trouble with the Hyperbolic tiles

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a hyerbolic shape with the graphics object to draw arcs, but the arcs are going the opposite way from how I want to draw them (kind of like a disjointed circle). Does anyone know how to fix this?

```js
for ( int x1 = 0; x1 < 50; x1++ )
      {
       for(int y1 = 0; y1 < 50; y1++)
       {
        rotation = randomNum.nextInt(4) + 1;
        //System.out.println(rotation);
         // pick the pattern based on the user's choice
        switch (choice)
        {
         case 1: //Arcs
          if(rotation == 1 || rotation == 3){
           g.drawArc(x1 * size, y1 * size, size, size, 0, 90);
           g.drawArc(x1 * size, y1 * size, size, size, 180, 90);
          }
          else{
           g.drawArc(x1 * size, y1 * size, size, size, 90 , 90); //Rotate image
           g.drawArc(x1 * size, y1 * size, size, size, 270 , 90); //Rotate image
          }
```